# Can't get filter to work for querying datastore in Google App Engine (Python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Not sure what's going wrong.  I'm trying to query a simple string in a datastore, but the query always comes out empty.

models.py:

```
from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.api import datastore_types

class Post(db.Model):
    author = db.TextProperty()
    title = db.TextProperty()
    slug = db.TextProperty()
    #slug = str()
```

main.py:

```
import wsgiref.handlers
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import util
from models import *
import logging
import os

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'
from google.appengine.dist import use_library
use_library('django', '1.2')
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify


class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):

        # store some random posts
        title1 = "Road to the perfect car wax."
        title2 = "10 ways to get a perfect car wax."
        slug1 = slugify(title1)
        slug2 = slugify(title2)

        post1 = Post(author="Tom Tomton", title=title1, slug=str(slug1))
        post2 = Post(author="John Jonston", title=title2, slug=str(slug2))

        posts = list()
        posts.append(post1)
        posts.append(post2)
        db.put(posts)

        # use filter to find a post
        q = Post.all()
        q.filter("slug =",str(slug1))
        #q.filter("slug =","road-to-the-perfect-car-wax")
        result = q.fetch(1)[0] # empty!
        logging.info("result: %s" % result) 

        self.response.out.write('<p class="item">%s, %s</p>' % (result.author, result.title))


application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/.*', MainHandler)], debug=True)


def main():
    wsgiref.handlers.CGIHandler().run(application)
    #util.run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The output in the datastore viewer clearly shows it's right there though:

```
2   1   None    Tom Tomton  road-to-the-perfect-car-wax     Road to the perfect car wax.
2   2   None    John Jonston    10-ways-to-get-a-perfect-car-wax    10 ways to get a perfect car wax.
```

I've tried using app engine versions 1.5.5 and 1.5.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TextProperty`s are not indexed, and can't be filtered on. Use `StringProperty` if you need an index.

Comment: Also note that after switching this over, you'll need to fetch and `.put()` all your entities for them to be indexed.